AWS Athena with Iceberg: convert timestamp string with timezone into a timestamp column
I have the following string:
2024-02-28T14:26:51.292534-03:00

I want to convert it to a timestamp column without losing any data. I tried different solutions such as the following, but none worked:

from_iso8601_timestamp
cast as timestamp(6)
parse_datetime

Which is the best way to convert it? Here is the desired output for my request:
data: 2024-02-28 17:26:51.292534 UTC

typeof: timestamp(6) with time zone

